# Django How to paginate a list of dicts

Tags: python, django, pagination

I have this function where I get data from the Stackoverflow Api as you can see below and I display them in an html table.
Is there a way to have pagination for this list of dicts so that 10 results appear on each page?

**views.py:**

```
def get_questions(request):
    context = {}
    url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions'
    params = {  'fromdate':'1525858177',
                'todate':'1525904006',
                'order':'desc',
                'sort':'activity',
                'tagged':'python',
                'site':'stackoverflow'
            }
    r = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
    dataList = []
    for item in r['items']:
        dataList.append({
            'owner': item['owner']['display_name'],
            'title': item['title'],
            'creation_date': datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(item['creation_date'])),
            'is_answered': item['is_answered'], # (yes / no)
            'view_count': item['view_count'],
            'score':item['score'],
            'link':item['link'],
            'answer_count':item['answer_count']
        })

    template = 'questions/questions_list.html'
    context['data'] = dataList
    return render(request,template,context)
```

**questions_list.html:**

```
  <table id="myTable" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Owner</th>
        <th scope="col">Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Creation date</th>
        <th scope="col">Is answered</th>
        <th scope="col">View count</th>
        <th scope="col">Score</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for d in data %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ d.owner }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ d.link }}" target="blank">{{ d.title }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ d.creation_date }}</td>
        <td>{{ d.is_answered|yesno:"yes,no" }}</td>
        <td>{{ d.view_count }}</td>
        <td>{{ d.score }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Personally, i used to add https://datatables.net/. The pagination will be generated in the front-end through datatable javascript library.

Comment: `from django.core.paginator import Paginator`, the point of django is that *everything* is built-in

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos well you just blew my mind! Didn't know that existed! Thank you!!! Please create an answer so I can close the question!

Comment: @DanaeVogiatzi just did it. You are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Django provides a few classes that help you manage paginated data – that is, data that’s split across several pages, with “Previous/Next” links. These classes live in django/core/paginator.py.

Give Paginator a list of objects, plus the number of items you’d like to have on each page, and it gives you methods for accessing the items for each page:

```
>>> from django.core.paginator import Paginator
>>> objects = ['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo']
>>> p = Paginator(objects, 2)

>>> p.count
4
>>> p.num_pages
2
>>> type(p.page_range)
<class 'range_iterator'>
>>> p.page_range
range(1, 3)

>>> page1 = p.page(1)
>>> page1
<Page 1 of 2>
>>> page1.object_list
['john', 'paul']

>>> page2 = p.page(2)
>>> page2.object_list
['george', 'ringo']
>>> page2.has_next()
False
>>> page2.has_previous()
True
>>> page2.has_other_pages()
True
>>> page2.next_page_number()
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
EmptyPage: That page contains no results
>>> page2.previous_page_number()
1
>>> page2.start_index() # The 1-based index of the first item on this page
3
>>> page2.end_index() # The 1-based index of the last item on this page
4

>>> p.page(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
EmptyPage: That page number is less than 1
>>> p.page(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
EmptyPage: That page contains no results
```

I hope these example code snippets helps resolving your query!

Comment: This blog post is really helpful: 
https://dontrepeatyourself.org/post/django-pagination-with-function-based-view/

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is using [datatables.net](http://datatables.net)

It's very easy to install and still the pagination will be done in the frontend.

Simply add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> </script>
```

Also, do not forget to add jQuery.

Then just call a simple jQuery function

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );
```

Comment: This was wrong.Why ? you are sending buld array to front end and let front end paginate it by it self. so better paginate in backend and lazy load to front end

Answer (score 0):

You can use basically DRF, overriding the class-based view  ModelViewSet , adding the pagination class.You can then easily customize the pagination displaying 100, 20, 10 and so forth.

```
from rest_framework import views, viewsets, authentication, permissions,pagination   
class  A (viewsets.ModelViewSet):
          pagination_class = pagination.PageNumberPagination
          page_size = 100

       def get_questions(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           #Your code here 
           #intercete the code and inject this here
           if request.GET.get('page', None) is not None:
              self.page_size = request.GET.get('page_size',self.page_size)
              page = self.paginate_queryset(self.queryset.order_by(order_by))
           else:
               #Something else
```